# Where is the documentation for the IP variable in initramfs.conf?

Tags: ip, initramfs, documentation

Multiple sources, including [this one](https://www.eugenemdavis.com/set-static-ip-initramfs.html), mention using the IP variable in initramfs.conf to set a static IP address in the pre-boot environment, and I have used this successfully in the past. However, the man page for initramfs doesn't mention it, and I can't find any documentation for it. Is there any? If so where?

Answer (score 4):

This should be the missing pieces:

man page [initramfs.conf(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/initramfs-tools-core/initramfs.conf.5.en.html) (Debian buster)

> **VARIABLES FOR NFS BOOT**
>
> `DEVICE`
>
> Specifies the default network interface to use, like eth0. The *ip* or *BOOTIF* bootargs may override this.

---

man page [initramfs-tools(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/initramfs-tools-core/initramfs-tools.7.en.html) (Debian buster)

> `ip`
>   tells how to configure the ip address. Allows one to specify an different NFS server than the DHCP server. See Documentation/filesystems/nfsroot.txt in any recent Linux source for details. Optional parameter for NFS root.

---

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt:

> ```
> ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:
>    <dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>:<ntp0-ip>
> ```
>
> This parameter tells the kernel how to configure IP addresses of devices
>   and also how to set up the IP routing table. It was originally called
>   `nfsaddrs`, but now the boot-time IP configuration works independently of
>   NFS, so it was renamed to `ip` and the old name remained as an alias for
>   compatibility reasons.
>
> If this parameter is missing from the kernel command line, all fields are
>   assumed to be empty, and the defaults mentioned below apply. In general
>   this means that the kernel tries to configure everything using
>   autoconfiguration.
>
> ...